# CLLocationManager delegate not receiving location updates after application is suspended despite background location updates enabled

Tags: swift, background, location, cllocationmanager

I'm attempting to receive location updates while my application is suspended - according to the documentation I've read, this shouldn't be an issue and I am following all the required steps, yet once the application is suspended, location updates do not seem to occur.

I've seen similar posts that have solutions involving the use of startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges, but according to my understanding of the documentation, I shouldn't need to implement this on top of startUpdatingLocation.

According to the documentation, if background location updates are enabled, the system will be suspended but will be woken up when there is new location data.

Since the documentation states **"In the case of a suspended app, the system wakes up the app, delivers the update to the location manager’s delegate"** I expect I can process the location updates the same as if the application is in the foreground or in the background.

I have location updates selected in the Capabilities tab and in the info.plist the key UIBackgroundModes includes location in the array of values.

What am I missing?

For reference, this is how I am declaring my CLLocationManager.

```
lazy var locationManager: CLLocationManager = {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.activityType = .fitness
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = true
    return locationManager
}()
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1

**"You enable location support from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. (You can also enable this support by including the UIBackgroundModes key with the location value in your app’s Info.plist file.) Enabling this mode does not prevent the system from suspending the app, but it does tell the system that it should wake up the app whenever there is new location data to deliver. Thus, this key effectively lets the app run in the background to process location updates whenever they occur."**

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1

**"The system delivers location updates to background location apps when the app is in the foreground, is running in the background, or is suspended. In the case of a suspended app, the system wakes up the app, delivers the update to the location manager’s delegate, and then returns the app to the suspended state as soon as possible."**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and the only way to prevent the app from beeing suspended was to set

```
locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
```

When `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` is set to `true` the systems puts the app in suspended state and will not receive location changes anymore until the user manually brings the app to foreground again.